# PostGIS Raster AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgis, raster, aws-dms

I am using AWS DMS to populate an RDS PostgreSQL 12 database with the postgis  and postgis_raster extensions installed.

I am getting the following error when DMS is populating its data

```
ERROR: rt_raster_from_wkb: wkb size (0)  < min size (61); Error while executing the query [1022502]
```

I would like to resolve this error so data import into the database

Comment: can you add the `WKB` that is causing the problem?

Comment: I reached out to AWS support and it seems DMS does not support the raster type at this point in time. We are working around the problem at this point in time